# Webpack: Files not showing in the browser DevTool

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I am trying to setup a project using webpack/react/redux etc. I have setup the project but I can't see the project files in the dev-tools in my browser. I searched online and found that using

```
debug : true,
devtool : 'source-map'
```

in my webpack config file will make files appear in dev-tools but they still ain't showing up. I can only see my `bundle.js` in dev-tools

My whole webpack.config.js file is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/client.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: require("path").resolve("./dist"),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        excludes: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre']   //query will tell what bable-loader has to do, which is compiling JSX(react) and es2015
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    configFile: './.eslintrc'
  }
};
```

How can I see all the project files in devtools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your webpack configuration.

Since you are able to see `bundle.js` file, obviously there should be a `webpack://` folder. Under that, you could see a folder with name `.`. Expand that, you might see your source files.

Comment: Thanks, It can easily be missed by a beginner like me. :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these two proporties to your webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
mode: 'development',
devtool : 'eval-source-map',
.....the rest of your webpack.config
}
```